# how to count the number of characters and ignore space in C

Tags: c

Following is my code, when I enter "carol chen", I expect it will print out 9 characters, but it print out 10.

The name you enter is: carol chen

The number of characters in the user's name is 10

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

char *name;
int i;
int n = 0;

name= (char *)calloc(80, sizeof(char));

if(name == NULL) {

    printf("\nOut of memory!\n");
    return 1;
}
else {

    printf("The name you enter is: ");
    scanf("%79[0-9a-zA-Z ]", name);

    for(i=0; i<80; i++){

        if(name[i] != 0){

            n += 1;
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe number of characters in the user's name is %d\n", n);

}

free(name);

}
```

Comment: +1 for checking the value returned by calloc(). Just scan for 80 characters, i.e. scanf("%80s", name) and then check each character in your loop to see if it's printable. You're almost there.

Comment: There's no point in using `calloc()` and `free()` when simply writing `char name[80];` would give you as much space with far less overhead.

Comment: @Jonathan That's true, but I want to make Dynamic Memory Allocation, so that I can use realloc() after. Thank you.

Comment: @MickSharpe: Note that there's an 'off-by-one' design decision in `scanf()` et al.  If your variable is `char name[80];`, the format string should be `"%79s"` — you specify the number of characters excluding the trailing null.  This is a sad inconsistency with other functions, but was frozen long before the C standard was defined (circa 1979), and changing it would have broken working code.  (That's how `gets()` survived until C11 too — backwards compatibility!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just don't count the spaces by adding an `and` clause that excludes spaces inside your `if` condition:

Try this:

```
if (name[i] != 0 && name[i] != ' ')
{
    n += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more efficient version

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        char *name;
        int i;
        int n = 0;

        name= (char *)calloc(80, sizeof(char));

        if(name == NULL) {
            printf("\nOut of memory!\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            printf("The name you enter is: ");
            scanf("%79[0-9a-zA-Z ]", name);
        }

        i = 0;
        while ( (i < 80) && name[i])  {
            if(name[i] != ' ') {
                n += 1;
            }
            i++;
        }
        printf("\nThe number of characters in the user's name is %d\n", n);

        free(name);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain why it is more efficient?  I guess you're thinking it will stop on reaching the first null byte, rather than scanning 70 of them.  You could still use a `for` loop rather than losing the `i++` down at the end of the `while`.  Many C programmers would use `n++;` in place of `n += 1;` though the result is the same.

Comment: @Peter Thank you!

Comment: Jonathan your comments are valid. I quickly modified the code to show Yotta a better way of doing it, rather than going through the whole array. It is not the way I would have written the code.